# Prepend element to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, insert

I have the following numpy array

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[5.], [4.], [3.], [2.], [1.]])
```

I want to insert `[6.]` at the beginning.
I've tried:

```
X = X.insert(X, 0)
```

how do I insert into X?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

numpy has an `insert` function that's accesible via `np.insert` with [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html).

You'll want to use it in this case like so:

```
X = np.insert(X, 0, 6., axis=0)
```

the first argument `X` specifies the object to be inserted into.

The second argument `0` specifies where.

The third argument `6.` specifies what is to be inserted.

The fourth argument `axis=0` specifies that the insertion should happen at position `0` for every column.  We could've chosen rows but your X is a columns vector, so I figured we'd stay consistent.

Comment: More about axis=0 is here https://medium.com/@panjeh/numpy-insert-prepend-element-to-numpy-array-with-axis-parameter-875296ed87af

Answer (score 67):

I just wrote some code that does this operation ~100,000 times, so I needed to figure out the fastest way to do this. I'm not an expert in code efficiency by any means, but I could figure some things out by using the `%%timeit` magic function in a jupyter notebook.

My findings:

`np.concatenate(([number],array))`
requires the least time. Let's call it 1x time.

`np.asarray([number] + list(array))`
comes in at ~2x.

`np.r_[number,array]`
is ~4x.

`np.insert(array,0,number)`
appears to be the worst option here at 8x.

I have no idea how this changes with the size of `array` (I used a shape (15,) array) and most of the options I suggested only work if you want to put the number at the beginning. However, since that's what the question is asking about, I figure this is a good place to make these comparisons.

Comment: Awesome! Not only the first option is faster, but can be easily used to insert an entire sequence ... for example, in my case, I wanted to insert several zeros at the begging; `aa =np.concatenate(([0]*99, aa))` ... as I was manipulating a signal prior to smoothing, then finding the peaks.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following

```
X = np.append(arr = np.array([[6]]), values = X, axis= 0)
```

Instead of inserting 6 to the existing X, let append 6 by X.

So, first argument `arr` is numpy array of scalar 6, second argument is your array to be added, and third is the place where we want to add

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old one, but a short solution is using numpy slicing tricks:

```
np.r_[[[6.]], X]
```

If you need to do it in a second dimension you can use np.c_.

I think this is the least cluttered version I can think of

Comment: BTW: you can append this way as well by simply reversing the order of course.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the comment of jbf81tb, as of 2023, all variants but the one with conversion to list, are more or less equal:

```
arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
%timeit np.concatenate(([-1],arr))
1.33 ms ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
%timeit np.asarray([-1] + list(arr))
63.7 ms ± 691 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
%timeit np.r_[-1,arr]
1.41 ms ± 35.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
%timeit np.insert(arr,0,-1)
1.39 ms ± 24.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```