# Integrate a function with each element of numpy arrays as limit of integration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a function in python (using scipy and numpy also) defined as

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
LCDMf = lambda x: 1.0/np.sqrt(0.3*(1+x)**3+0.7)
```

I would like to integrate it from 0 to each element in a numpy array say `z = np.arange(0,100)`

I know I can write a loop for each element iterating through like

```
an=integrate.quad(LCDMf,0,z[i])
```

But, I was wondering if there is a faster, efficient (and simpler) way to do this with each numpy element.

Comment: I remember long ago solving this problem using np.vectorize method. I can't quite recall how I did it... But it seemed like a universal solution at the time and worked for me. Anybody can throw light on it solving in similar direction?

Comment: `np.vectorize` just wraps the iteration in a function call.  It doesn't speed up your code.

Comment: I used it to work on numpy arrays somehow... not for speeding up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering with `np.vectorize` I found the following solution. Simple - elegant and it works!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
LCDMf = lambda x: 1.0/math.sqrt(0.3*(1+x)**3+0.7)
np.vectorize(LCDMf)

def LCDMfint(z):
    return integrate.quad(LCDMf, 0, z)

LCDMfint=np.vectorize(LCDMfint)
z=np.arange(0,100)

an=LCDMfint(z)
print an[0]
```

This method works with unsorted float arrays or anything we throw at it and doesn't any initial conditions as in the odeint method.

I hope this helps someone somewhere too... Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 5):

You could rephrase the problem as an ODE.

[image]

The [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) function can then be used to compute `F(z)` for a series of `z`.

```
>>> scipy.integrate.odeint(lambda y, t: LCDMf(t), 0, [0, 1, 2, 5, 8])
array([[ 0.        ],    # integrate until z = 0 (must exist, to provide initial value)
       [ 0.77142712],    # integrate until z = 1
       [ 1.20947123],    # integrate until z = 2
       [ 1.81550912],    # integrate until z = 5
       [ 2.0881925 ]])   # integrate until z = 8
```

Comment: Interesting work-around. But having to have a '0' value thing for initial condition is kind of limiting and doesn't seem universal to me. Say, if I want to integrate with z varying from 0.1 to 0.5 for e.g.

Comment: @RohinKumar You could just always [prepend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998260/prepend-element-to-numpy-array) a 0.

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely be done more efficiently.  In the end what you've got is a series of calculations:

1. Integrate LCDMf from 0 to 1.
2. Integrate LCDMf from 0 to 2.
3. Integrate LCDMf from 0 to 3.

So the very first thing you can do is change it to integrate distinct subintervals and then sum them (after all, what else is integration!):

1. Integrate LCDMf from 0 to 1.
2. Integrate LCDMf from 1 to 2, add result from step 1.
3. Integrate LCDMf from 2 to 3, add result from step 2.

Next you can dive into LCDMf, which is defined this way:

```
1.0/np.sqrt(0.3*(1+x)**3+0.7)
```

You can use NumPy broadcasting to evaluate this function at many points instantly:

```
dx = 0.0001
x = np.arange(0, 100, dx)
y = LCDMf(x)
```

That should be quite fast, and gives you one million points on the curve.  Now you can integrate it using [`scipy.integrate.trapz()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapz.html#scipy.integrate.trapz) or one of the related functions.  Call this with the y and dx already computed, using the workflow above where you integrate each interval and then use `cumsum()` to get your final result.  The only function you need to call in a loop then is the integrator itself.

Comment: May be I didn't quite follow your solution.  0 to 1, 0 to 2 etc. is an example case. It need not always be equally spaced or be integer. So, say z=[0.1, 0.15, 0.367, 0.265...] What happens then?

Comment: Well you said `z = np.arange(0,100)` but if you have some other `z` then just sort it first and my solution should still work--simply integrate from 0 to the smallest `z` value, then from that `z` to the next-smallest `z`, etc.