# Python plotting a function with an integration

Tags: python, plot, numerical-integration

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np


def g(t):
    return integrate.quad(t, 0, t)


def f(t):
    return t ** 3 - g(t)


t1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1))
plt.show()
```

Here, it is the error message I got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without broadcasting it can be done like this.

```
import numpy as np


def g(t):
    g_value= integrate.quad (lambda t: t, 0, t)
    return (g_value)

def f(t):
    f_value = t**3 - g(t)
    return (f_value)

t1 = np.arange (-5, 5, 0.1)
ft1 = []
for tt in t1:
    ft1.append(f(tt)[0])

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, ft1)
plt.show()
```

Vectorized version can be done like this [(mentioned here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718128/integrate-a-function-with-each-element-of-numpy-arrays-as-limit-of-integration)

```
import numpy as np
def g(t):
    g_value= integrate.quad (lambda t: t ,0,t)
    return (g_value)

g_vectorized = np.vectorize(g)

def f(t):
    f_value = t**3 - g_vectorized(t)
    return (f_value)

t1 = np.arange (-5, 5, 0.1)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1)[0])
plt.show()
```

Both of them result in

[image]

Comment: Now, it says: "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (2, 100)"