# how to insert numbers (i+1) in ndarray at the beginning?

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, numpy-ndarray

I have ndarray in npz file and I'm trying to insert numbers at index 0 and inserted numbers should be increase by 1.
Below is my array

```
data = [[[3.56, 7.94, 1.78], [8.23, 1.25, 4.80], [0.51, 8.23, 5.67], [9.56, 7.94, 2.78], [5.23, 7.25, 0.80],...]]
```

And the resulted ndarray should like

```
data = [[[0, 3.56, 7.94, 1.78], [1, 8.23, 1.25, 4.80], [2, 0.51, 8.23, 5.67], [3, 9.56, 7.94, 2.78], [4, 5.23, 7.25, 0.80],...]]
```

I'm new in this field so I want some help to solve this problem.

Moreover I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998260/prepend-element-to-numpy-array) but it is for 1D array.

My sample code is

```
import numpy as np

a = np.load('abc.npz')['data']
b = a.insert(a, 0+1) # I'm confused here
np.savez('new.npz', data=b)
```

Looking for some suggestions

Comment: So you want to append a new number at the beginning of each sub-array?

Comment: Yes same as I showed a resulted array.

Comment: For this you need to use numpy.stack family of operations

Comment: What is the shape of your array?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Array shape is `(1, 5, 3)` but after inserting element in the start of every sub-array then it should be `(1, 5, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. As Dani Mesejo helped me and I got some idea from him.

Below is solution

```
data = data.tolist()
for index, d in enumerate(data[:]): # slicing
    d.insert(0, index) # insert numbers in 0 index of every list.
```

The idea was to convert ndarray to list and then we can save it in npz or json after serialization

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[3.56, 7.94, 1.78], [8.23, 1.25, 4.80], [0.51, 8.23, 5.67], [9.56, 7.94, 2.78], [5.23, 7.25, 0.80]]])

res = np.insert(data, 0, np.arange(data.shape[1]), axis=2)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[[0.   3.56 7.94 1.78]
  [1.   8.23 1.25 4.8 ]
  [2.   0.51 8.23 5.67]
  [3.   9.56 7.94 2.78]
  [4.   5.23 7.25 0.8 ]]]
```

From the documentation, on [insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

> Insert values along the given axis before the given indices.

So basically you need to specify the array (`data`), the indices (`0`), the values to insert (`np.arange(data.shape[1])`) and the axis.

Comment: Thanks for solution, this solution can work but this is giving float numbers (0., 1., 2.,,,,) What if we need only integer? I mean inserted numbers should be integers.

Comment: @Erric You cannot have integer and floats in the same array, the other elements are floats.  In numpy arrays all elements must have the same type. You could try using dtype object but I don't recommend it

Comment: So there is no way to add as indexing or may be we can write new file in json?

Comment: What do you mean by "add as indexing", why do you need that, why don't simply use the indices already defined for arrays?

Comment: Actually I need the integers.

Comment: If you need integer indexes, simply refer to the array size, as Dani Mesejo suggested: (np.arange(data.shape[1])) If you save it in the array the data type will be the same for all the numbers